# How to create Minimap in LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx

I'm creating Minimap based on different rooms. I've finished all code related on displaying the correct rooms like in world.

Now it is just ArrayList of Sprites with different positions.

It looks like this:

[image]

I faced some problems.

**First:**

I don't know how to place it into frame.

**Second:**

I want to scroll it and move it on finger touch.

I guess that it should be some Group of Actors.

I looked on [Group](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Group.html) class and all it's inheritors and it isn't looking like there is Actor that can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use actors you need to have an Image to show the TextureRegion it doesnt work with Sprite. A Dialog to popup and hide and a ScrollPane to enable scrolling of the minimap.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog( "", skin );
Table widget = new Table( skin );

// GameObject is a generic class use your project values
for ( GameObject gameObject : gameObjects ){
    // you'll need to check if the position is relative to the parent or it's relative to
    // the screen otherwise use the cell.setActorX() cell.setActorY()
    Image image = new Image( gameObject.textureRegion );
    image.setX( gameObject.x );
    image.setY( gameObject.y );

    widget.addActor( image );
}

ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane( widget );
scrollPane.setScrollingDisabled( false, false );

dialog.add( scrollPane ).width( width ).height( height );
```

To show and hid the dialog set this in update method/click listener.

```
dialog.show( stage );
dialog.hide();
```